# What does "sb can stomach doing sth" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've come across a YouTube video in which the Youtuber says :

> If **I can stomach doing this** publicly ,I might read to you the
>   comments that I made in 2016 on Facebook , they are cringy and just
>   awful.

What does "stomach doing" mean ? Is it derived from "to have the stomach for something" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of the word stomach as a verb:

> to be able to accept an unpleasant idea or watch something unpleasant (https://dictionary.cambridge.com)

So in this case the writer is suggesting that reading the comments she's made, publicly would be an unpleasant thing to do for her (may be due to the rude or offensive nature of the said comments), and if she could get over the unpleasantness of doing so, that is if she could bring her self to do so, she might be able to read the comments publicly.

To answer your question about the expression being derived from "have the stomach to do something", I should say, yes; these two expressions share the same meaning, more or less.